# Permission denied for a route implemented by a custom module

Tags: page-controller

Hello I have the same problem with the following code:

first_module.routing.yml:

```
first_module.content:
  path: '/first'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\first_module\Controller\FirstController::content'
    _title: 'Hello world'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

and the Controller:

```
<?php

/**
 *  @file
 *  Contains \Drupal\first_module\Controller\FirstController.
 */


 namespace Drupal\first_module\Controller;

 use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;


 class FirstController extends ControllerBase {

   public function content() {
     return array(
       '#type' => 'markup',
       '#markup' => t('Hello world'),
     );
   }
 }
```

And I receive the same "Access Denied" error every time I try to access this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested to me from @berramou the solution is:

> Add \ to Drupal\first_module\Controller\FirstController::content like
>   \Drupal\first_module\Controller\FirstController::content and clear
>   cash. – berramou 17 mins ago